How to create a draggable vertical line in pinescript - like in Gann Box
How do I create a draggable vertical line in pinescript?
I managed to create simple indicator based on Gann Box. I'm facing some issues since I'm a beginner at Pine Script coding:


How do I move the horizontal lines (price lines) up and down on the chart without editing the value on the indicator settings? Vertical lines I can move them left and right on the chart.
How can I move vertical line in the future? I cannot move vertical lines beyond the current bar.
Time label: I want to add labels on vertical Lines but It doesn't work.

 version=5
 indicator(title="Gann Box", overlay=true)

 //  Inputs

 L1 = input.float(62500, "Horizontal Line 1 Price", inline = "1")
 L2 = input.float(63750, "Horizontal Line 2 Price", inline = "2")
 L3 = input.float(65450, "Horizontal Line 3 Price", inline = "3") 

 CP1 = input.string(title='', options=[" Up", " Down"], defval=" Up", inline = "1")
 CP2 = input.string(title='', options=[" Up", " Down"], defval=" Up", inline = "2")
 CP3 = input.string(title='', options=[" Up", " Down"], defval=" Up", inline = "3")

 lineDate1 = input.time(timestamp("26 Apr 2024 13:30"), title="Line Location1")
 lineDate2 = input.time(timestamp("26 Apr 2024 14:30"), title="Line Location2")
 lineDate3 = input.time(timestamp("26 Apr 2024 15:30"), title="Line Location3")

 //
 var VLine1 = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na,
      color=color.green, width=2,style = line.style_solid, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
      var VLine2 = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na,
      color=color.green, width=2,style = line.style_solid, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
 var VLine3 = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na,
      color=color.green, width=2,style = line.style_solid, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
  
 // 
 line.set_xy1(VLine1, x=lineDate1, y=L1)
 line.set_xy2(VLine1, x=lineDate3, y=L1)

 line.set_xy1(VLine2, x=lineDate1, y=L2)
 line.set_xy2(VLine2, x=lineDate3, y=L2)

 line.set_xy1(VLine3, x=lineDate1, y=L3)
 line.set_xy2(VLine3, x=lineDate3, y=L3)


 Label1 = label.new(x=lineDate3, y=L1,text= "   " + str.tostring(L1) + "-" + CP1, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, size=size.normal, style=label.style_label_left, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
 Label2 = label.new(x=lineDate3, y=L2,text= "   " + str.tostring(L2) + "-" + CP2, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, size=size.normal, style=label.style_label_left, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
 Label3 = label.new(x=lineDate3, y=L3,text= "   " + str.tostring(L3) + "-" + CP3, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, size=size.normal, style=label.style_label_left, xloc=xloc.bar_time)

 // Make both trend lines once
 var vLine1 = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na,
      color=color.green, width=2,style = line.style_solid, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
 var vLine2 = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na,
      color=color.green, width=2,style = line.style_solid, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
 var vLine3 = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na,
      color=color.green, width=2,style = line.style_solid, xloc=xloc.bar_time)

 // Update the lines' location on every bar
 line.set_xy1(vLine1, x=lineDate1, y=L1)
 line.set_xy2(vLine1, x=lineDate1, y=L3)

 line.set_xy1(vLine2, x=lineDate2, y=L1)
 line.set_xy2(vLine2, x=lineDate2, y=L3)

 line.set_xy1(vLine3, x=lineDate3, y=L1)
 line.set_xy2(vLine3, x=lineDate3, y=L3)


instead of input.float, Use input.price() for draggable horizantal lines and  input.time for vertical lines.
